# Does OpenAL-Soft have an upper limit on the number of sources?

Tags: audio, game-engine, openal, openal-soft

I'm using [OpenAL-Soft](http://kcat.strangesoft.net/openal-soft) for a project, and right now I'm trying to decide whether I need to implement OpenAL source pooling.

Source pooling is somewhat cumbersome (I need to write code to "allocate" sources, as well as somehow decide when they can be "freed"), but necessary if the number of sources that can be generated by OpenAL is limited.

Since OpenAL-Soft is a software implementation of the OpenAL API, I wonder if the number of sources it can generate is actually limited by the underlying hardware. Theoretically, since all mixing is done in software, there might be no need to actually use one hardware channel per source.

However, I'm not sure about it. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that OpenAL-Soft indeed does have an upper limit on the number of sources, which can be defined in a config file. The default seems to be 256. It makes sense to limit the number of sources because of the associated CPU and memory costs. Looks like I'll end up implementing a source pool after all.

Answer (score 1):

I just took a peek at its header ... did not see anything pop out.
Here is working code which synthesizes then renders audio buffer data ... you could play with seeing if it accommodates your necessary number of sources

```
// gcc -o openal_play_wed   openal_play_wed.c  -lopenal -lm

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>    // gives malloc
#include <math.h>


#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <OpenAL/al.h>
#include <OpenAL/alc.h>
#elif __linux
#include <AL/al.h>
#include <AL/alc.h>
#endif

ALCdevice  * openal_output_device;
ALCcontext * openal_output_context;

ALuint internal_buffer;
ALuint streaming_source[1];

int al_check_error(const char * given_label) {

    ALenum al_error;
    al_error = alGetError();

    if(AL_NO_ERROR != al_error) {

        printf("ERROR - %s  (%s)\n", alGetString(al_error), given_label);
        return al_error;
    }
    return 0;
}

void MM_init_al() {

    const char * defname = alcGetString(NULL, ALC_DEFAULT_DEVICE_SPECIFIER);

    openal_output_device  = alcOpenDevice(defname);
    openal_output_context = alcCreateContext(openal_output_device, NULL);
    alcMakeContextCurrent(openal_output_context);

    // setup buffer and source

    alGenBuffers(1, & internal_buffer);
    al_check_error("failed call to alGenBuffers");
}

void MM_exit_al() {

    ALenum errorCode = 0;

    // Stop the sources
    alSourceStopv(1, & streaming_source[0]);        //      streaming_source
    int ii;
    for (ii = 0; ii < 1; ++ii) {
        alSourcei(streaming_source[ii], AL_BUFFER, 0);
    }
    // Clean-up
    alDeleteSources(1, &streaming_source[0]);
    alDeleteBuffers(16, &streaming_source[0]);
    errorCode = alGetError();
    alcMakeContextCurrent(NULL);
    errorCode = alGetError();
    alcDestroyContext(openal_output_context);
    alcCloseDevice(openal_output_device);
}

void MM_render_one_buffer() {

    /* Fill buffer with Sine-Wave */
    // float freq = 440.f;
    float freq = 100.f;
    float incr_freq = 0.1f;

    int seconds = 4;
    // unsigned sample_rate = 22050;
    unsigned sample_rate = 44100;
    double my_pi = 3.14159;
    size_t buf_size = seconds * sample_rate;

    short * samples = malloc(sizeof(short) * buf_size);

   printf("\nhere is freq %f\n", freq);
    int i=0;
    for(; i<buf_size; ++i) {
        samples[i] = 32760 * sin( (2.f * my_pi * freq)/sample_rate * i );

        freq += incr_freq;
        // incr_freq += incr_freq;
        // freq *= factor_freq;

        if (100.0 > freq || freq > 5000.0) {

            incr_freq *= -1.0f;
        }
    }

    /* upload buffer to OpenAL */
    alBufferData( internal_buffer, AL_FORMAT_MONO16, samples, buf_size, sample_rate);
    al_check_error("populating alBufferData");

    free(samples);

    /* Set-up sound source and play buffer */
    // ALuint src = 0;
    // alGenSources(1, &src);
    // alSourcei(src, AL_BUFFER, internal_buffer);
    alGenSources(1, & streaming_source[0]);
    alSourcei(streaming_source[0], AL_BUFFER, internal_buffer);
    // alSourcePlay(src);
    alSourcePlay(streaming_source[0]);

    // ---------------------

    ALenum current_playing_state;
    alGetSourcei(streaming_source[0], AL_SOURCE_STATE, & current_playing_state);
    al_check_error("alGetSourcei AL_SOURCE_STATE");

    while (AL_PLAYING == current_playing_state) {

        printf("still playing ... so sleep\n");

        sleep(1);   // should use a thread sleep NOT sleep() for a more responsive finish

        alGetSourcei(streaming_source[0], AL_SOURCE_STATE, & current_playing_state);
        al_check_error("alGetSourcei AL_SOURCE_STATE");
    }

    printf("end of playing\n");

    /* Dealloc OpenAL */
    MM_exit_al();

}   //  MM_render_one_buffer

int main() {

    MM_init_al();

    MM_render_one_buffer();
}
```